# Function involving For loop

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I've written the following function (the code includes the output):

```
f1[L_, n_] := 
For[i = 1, i < Length[L], i++, 
If[L[[i]][[1]] > n Or L[[i]][[2]] > n, Print["Bad"], Print["Good"]]]
f1[{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}}, 5]
Good
Good
Good
```

Instead of outputting "Good" thrice and "Bad" once.

Could someone please tell me where I went wrong? I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably better:

```
f[l_, n_] := Or @@@ Thread /@ Thread[l > n] /. {True -> "Bad", False -> "Good"}

l = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}};
f[l, 5]
(* {"Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad"} *)
```

Looping is strongly discouraged in Mathematica, but if you still want to stick with it:

```
f1[l_, n_] := For[i = 1, i <= Length[l], i++, 
                 If[Or[l[[i, 1]] > n , l[[i, 2]] > n], Print["Bad"], Print["Good"]]]
```

Comment: OK, I figured it out now. For some reason, using "Or" instead of "| |" was causing the problem. Thanks for the answers everyone. Also, I was off by one when I specified when the function should terminate.

Comment: "For some reason": for the same reason as `Sin[x] Integrate {x, 0, 1}` won't return `1-Cos[1]`.

Answer (score 6):

You told Mathematica to terminate at `i == Length[L]-1`, not at `Length[L]`. Additionally, your use of `Or` is almost certainly not what you intended. I advise reading the Mathematica documentation under `tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression`.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative using `Map` and a pure function `&` which are common Mathematica idioms:

```
f1[el_, n_] := (#[[1]] > n || #[[2]] > n) & /@ el /. {True -> "Bad", False -> "Good"}
```

The use of capital letters for variables, functions etc is discouraged as they may clash with built in definitions.

`Print` is also not much used, Mathematica will automatically display the return value from the function unless you tell it not to using a terminating `;`

Answer (score 3):

I strongly advocate the use of a functional idiom such as `Map` or `Thread` as shown in the answers by Belisarius and image_doctor.

But it is worth noting that you can get something close to your original syntax using Infix notation (see [this guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html) for more information. Aside from the issue with your termination condition, you were trying to use `Or` as an infix operator (like + is for `Plus`), instead of the correct infix form of `||`. You could if you really wanted to use `Or` as the infix operator by nesting it in the `~` infix symbols. But watch out! `Or` has higher precedence than equality/inequality, so you then have to wrap your conditions in parentheses. (See [this guide on precedence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/PrecedenceOfOperatorsInNotations.html).) The final expression would look like this:

```
f1[L_, n_] := 
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[L], i++, 
  If[(L[[i]][[1]] > n) ~ Or ~ (L[[i]][[2]] > n), 
  Print["Bad"], Print["Good"]] ]
```

Please be aware that I do *not* advocate this particular syntax, but am only showing it for educational purposes.

Personally, I'd suggest

```
 Max[#] > 5 & /@ {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}}
```

Or use the explicit form of `Map` (`/@`) to get at the individual matrix elements at level 2 of the list, and then `Apply` `Or` to each row using the short-form notation `@@@`.

```
Or @@@ Map[# > 5 &, {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}}, {2}]
```

Comment: _Please be aware that I do not advocate this particular syntax, but am only showing it for educational purposes_  +1. Coming soon to theaters "The wars of the mods" :D

Comment: Haha @Belisarius - I have nothing against infix in general, but you have to admit that `~ Or ~` is ungainly relative to `||`.

Answer (score 1):

```
f1[L_, n_] := 
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[L], i++, 
  If[Or[L[[i, 1]] > n , L[[i, 2]] > n], Print["Bad ", L[[i]]], 
   Print["Good ", L[[i]]]]]
```

You need to note the difference between:

`For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++; Print[i]] (* <= ;*)`

`For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, Print[i]] (* <= ,*)`

`For[i = 1, i < 10, i++; Print[i]]  (* < ; *)`

`For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, Print[i]]  (* < , *)`